# Append a text in container

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a container which displays the texts each time i click on a button. My code works fine but each time i click on a button the previous entry which is displayed in the container erases. I want to keep the previous entry and make the next text appear in the next line each time i click on a new button. Below is my code.Thank you

```js
function appChangeFunction() {    
  holdtext.innerText = appchange.innerText;
}

function sharedChangeFunction() {    
  holdtext.innerText = sharedchange.innerText;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" rows="15" cols="70"></TEXTAREA><br><br>
</div>

<style>#container {width:100%; text-align:center;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />

<button onclick="appChangeFunction()" style="background-color:white"    >App Change</button>&nbsp

<button onclick="sharedChangeFunction()" style="background-color:white" >Shared Change</button>&nbsp

<SPAN ID="appchange" STYLE="display:none"> Text Under App Change
  </SPAN>

<SPAN ID="sharedchange" STYLE="display:none"> Text Under Shared Change
</SPAN>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the old text to the new using `+` sign :

```
<script>
    function appChangeFunction() {    
        holdtext.innerText = holdtext.innerText + '\n' + appchange.innerText;
    }

    function sharedChangeFunction() {    
        holdtext.innerText = holdtext.innerText + '\n' + sharedchange.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

Or using `+=` sign and `\n` for new lines :

```
<script>
    function appChangeFunction() {    
        holdtext.innerText += '\n'+appchange.innerText;
    }

    function sharedChangeFunction() {    
        holdtext.innerText += '\n'+sharedchange.innerText;
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the newlines?

Comment: Wow.. Thanks a Lot Zakaria Acharki. Anyway to get this to next line

Comment: You're welcome. You forgot to add newlines in the first example though :3

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I would think that it would be the first complete/correct answer, which would be mine; but yours is more detailed anyways, so it deserves the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your script tag with:

```
<script>
function appChangeFunction() {    
holdtext.innerText += "\n"+appchange.innerText;
}

function sharedChangeFunction() {    
holdtext.innerText += "\n"+sharedchange.innerText;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to add a short explanation +1

Answer (score 0):

If first get the container data then it will be added the text

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" rows="30" cols="70">
</TEXTAREA><br><br>
</div>

<style>#container {width:100%; text-align:center;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />

<button onclick="appChangeFunction()"  style="background-color:white"    >App Change</button>&nbsp

 <button onclick="sharedChangeFunction()" style="background-color:white" >Shared Change</button>&nbsp

<SPAN ID="appchange" STYLE="display:none"> Text Under App Change
</span>

 <SPAN ID="sharedchange" STYLE="display:none"> Text Under Shared Change
</SPAN>

</body>
</html>
<script>
function appChangeFunction() { 
var x = document.getElementById("holdtext").innerHTML;   
holdtext.innerText = x + appchange.innerText;
}

function sharedChangeFunction() { 
var x = document.getElementById("holdtext").innerHTML;      
holdtext.innerText = x + sharedchange.innerText;
}
</script>
```